# Use Intel C++ Compiler (Composer) 2011 with Qt without Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, intel

Why does the intel compiler on Windows keep nagging about visual studio? I don't have visual studio and I don't want it!!! is that the only option I have??? I'm a Qt programmer who've been using MinGW as a compiler, and never needed Visual Studio. On Linux, the intel compiler is totally independent and doesn't need any other compilers to work. Could anyone please explain what's the deal with this Intel Compiler and why it's not standalone?

Please tell me what I should do to get it to work with Qt without Visual Studio.

Edit: To be clear about the problem, when I try to use icl.exe to compile some file, it gives me this error:

icl: error #10114: Microsoft Visual C++ not found in path

Thanks for any efforts! :-)

Comment: On Windows, the Intel compiler normally uses the VC++ standard library, so at the very least you'd have to get it to use some alternative standard library.

Answer (score 0):

On no platform is the Intel C/C++ compiler standalone. It requires tools of various kinds on all platforms.

The official documentation actually does list the entire `gcc` toolchain as a system requirement on Linux. Additional libraries are required as well.

It just so happens that on Windows, these tools are bundled with Visual Studio. The free version is sufficient.

Comment: The free version? Do you mean Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Yes, VSE is sufficient to run ICC.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A stupid question, though. There's not a way to run it with MinGW, is there?

Comment: You still need VSE, but you can build for MinGW. Use `-DMINGW32`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have installed Visual C++ Express, but the Intel C++ Composer installer can't detect it, and integration with Visual Studio option is disabled in the installer!!! It says that prerequisites are not there. Should I do something special to have it detected?

Comment: You may have the wrong version or VCE installed for your version of the Intel C compiler.

Comment: How can I check that? The Intel Compiler I'm using supports Visual Studio 2010. What kind of incompatibility are you pointing to?